# Angular directive restrict 'A'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

For some reason, none of my directives with a `restrict: 'A'` are working inside a `ui-view`.
If I change the restriction to `'E'` - it works.

```
<test></test> // working with 'E'
<div test></div> // not working with 'A'
```

I think it is somehow related to the ui-router since as soon as I move the directive outside of the ui-view in to the root - it works.

Here is a plunker where I tried to reproduce my issue, but unfortunately it works there...
http://plnkr.co/edit/B3lLpXAF1zRdsNNt00V9?p=preview

Comment: create a nested demo that replicates problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the `gulp-minify-html` plugin. I had to add the `empty: true` option to prevent it from removing empty attributes.